# Show convergence in mean

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X(t)$ is a positive i.i.d. random process in discrete time with finite mean $a$. Let $Y(t)=\min \{a, X(t)\}$.

Question is:

(1)Can we claim that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(\mid\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t} Y(i)}{t}-a\mid)=0$?

What I actually want is $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{t} Y(i)}{t}=a$ which I believe follows from above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For example, suppose $X(t) = a+1$ (and thus $Y(t) = a$) with probability $1/2$ and $X(t) = Y(t) = a-1$ with probability $1/2$.   Thus in this case
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{t} {\mathbb E} \sum_{i=1}^t Y(i) = a - \frac12$$